# UITableView crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Anyone got any ideas why this Table View code is crashing?

This, in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", nil];
```

Then, this in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item (%@)", [itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

When I scroll down (i.e. so that object 1 goes off screen) then scroll back to try and see object 1, it crashes at this previous line.

It's fine if I replace the offending line with something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
```

---

UPDATE: Answer was that the array was not being retained.
This line fixed the problem:

```
itemArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", nil] retain];
```

OR

```
itemArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", nil];
```

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to say, but is your array a different size than the number of rows in your table?

Comment: The fact that it's fine initially but crashes when you scroll a cell off and back on the screen indicates that there may be a problem with ReuseIdenitifiers.

Comment: Common guys, try to use what you have. If you'd have symobilicated stacktrace even baby could do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your itemArray seems not to be retained. `arrayWithObjects:` returns an autoreleased object. You need to `retain` or `copy` it, or use the syntactic sugar of a retaining property.

Comment: Or, if it's declared and has `property(nonatomic, retain)` and is `synthesize`d, then do `[self setItemArray:...]` instead.

Comment: @Eiko if it would be retain issue, it would crush right away on first `-objectAtIndex:` call in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @bioffe. No, not necessarily. The view might get loaded when the table asks for the cells for the first time, hence the autorelease pool can still be around.

Comment: @bioffe that array not releasing immediately but after some time, so it don't crush on first `-objectAtIndex`.

Comment: @Eiko Offtopic: I started iOS programming with a chess program as well back in 2007. Long before you guys arrived. Check my profile.

Comment: @Eiko: thanks - a retain fixed it. I've updated the original question with the code I used. One question though - I declared itemArray in the .h file and then used an @property (with nonatomic, retain) and @synthesize. Wasn't that sufficient to retain the array?

Comment: @Snow Crash You need to invoke the setter method by either using `[self setItemArray: ...]` or the dot syntax `self.itemArray = ...;` In those cases, it will get retained according to your property declaration. Be sure not to retain it manually *and* using the setter.